# Magento 2 : How to make "lastname " optional in customer registration form?

Tags: customer, forms, magento2.1.6

I need to make **lastname** optional in customer registration form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you should remove the `is_required` option from the lastname attributes in the customer entity and address entity:

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required`=0 WHERE `attribute_code`='lastname'
```

Then you should rewrite registration form of your theme. In the default magento setup this template is located here:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml

You should remove validation and required class from the lastname label and lastname input, like:

```
<div class="field field-name-lastname">
    <label class="label"  for="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFieldId('lastname') ?>">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getStoreLabel('lastname') ?></span>
    </label>

    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFieldId('lastname') ?>"
               name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFieldName('lastname') ?>"
               value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>"
               title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getStoreLabel('lastname') ?>"
               class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') ?>" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFieldParams() ?>>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Important Note:** Do not change the original file! You should do it in a custom module or theme!

Comment: Hi Siarhey Uchukhlebau, thanks for quick reply. it works fine, but i am importing customers from m1 to m2, while importing some of the customers are not imported, why because customer last name was empty. But your solution works fine in frontend, any idea to fix while importing data.

Comment: @balu Which script you are using ?

Comment: one paid extension : magento2magento2_v3.0.2 , by using this extension we are importing data from magento 1 to magento 2.

Comment: @balu Sorry, but I cant help you without source code :(

Comment: No problem, Thank you very much , your solution helpful in register account and address edit scenaries.

Comment: ok, but...what happend whit the admin panel ? when you try to save/update a info user you cant because lastname already is required

Comment: @Charly you must change the form in backend too. I will check it tomorrow and update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think that it would be better to update the

`is_required`

option through upgrade script instead of run a query directly on database.

You should create in your module an `UpgradeData.php` in this path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup

and put inside this code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<=')) {
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->updateAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'lastname', 'is_required', 0);
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Then run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to apply to database

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This updates the DB Entry, but does not pass through the JS validation in admin panel.