# Declarative schema approach to make customer's lastname optional

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, declarative-schema

With pre-2.3 Magento versions we were able to write `UpgradeData` code and make customer's lastname optional as mentioned here: [Magento 2 : How to make “lastname ” optional in customer registration form?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/228563/9169)
 .

How I can make customer's lastname optional using declarative schema approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2.3 has introduced [Data Patch](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html) classes which contains data modification instructions.

If you want to update existing table data, you can create a datapatch class at `Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/<Data_Patch_Class>.php` and make the required modification there.

To make customer's lastname optional I have used following code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class LastnameOptional implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['resourceConnection' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->updateAttribute('customer', 'lastname', 'is_required', 0);
        $customerSetup->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'lastname', 'is_required', 0);
    }
}
```